# Send post params on httpClient with square brackets

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, cloudsight

I'm trying to make an http request to a webservice called CloudSight, and I need to pass via post a series of parameters which, in explaining the documentation indicates that they should be bracketed.
The curl example they offer is as follows:

```
Curl -i -X ??POST \
-H "Authorization: CloudSight [key]" \
-F "image_request [image] = @ Image.jpg" \
-F "image_request [locale] = en-US"
-F "image_request [language] = en" \
Https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests
```

In Titanium I have tried the following:

```
Var request = {
Image_request['image']: self.image,
Image_request['locale']: 'es-ES',
Image_request['language']: 'is',
};
...
Xhr.send (request);
```

And I get the following error:
[ERROR]: Unexpected token, expected, (43:13)

I've also tried the following

```
Var myArray = [];
MyArray['image'] = self.image;
MyArray['locale'] = 'es-ES';
MyArray['language'] = 'es';
Var request = {
Image_request: myArray
};
...
Xhr.send (request);
```

In this case the application runs, but when I call the webservice I receive a 500 error.
Some help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If image_request [] are the parameters name then you can try something like below

```
Var request = {
"image_request[image]": self.image,
"image_request[locale]": 'es-ES',
"image_request[language]": 'es',
};
```

OR

```
Var request = {
"image": self.image,
"locale": 'es-ES',
"language": 'es',
};
```

Also confirm that server accepts json object otherwise you need to stringify it.

```
Xhr.send (JSON.stringify(request));
```

Explain more about the api parameters if it does not work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have placed the names of the parameters in quotation marks, as you have advised me and it worked perfectly.